# Metric on $[-\infty,\infty]$ by homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to precise a topology to use on $[-\infty,\infty]$. This space is homeomorphic to  $[0,1]$ by taking $$f(x) = \tan (\pi(x-1/2))$$ as map. Taking $d(x,y) = |x-y|$, $x,y\in[0,1]$ can I "map" the metric using $f$ to get a metric on $[-\infty,\infty]$? Maybe $\overline{d}(x,y) = d(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y))$ would work?

Comment: Yes, it would. It's a standard way of transporting metrics.

Comment: Another less know isometry is $$\frac{x}{1+|x|}$$

Comment: @PeterTamaroff how is that? From $[-\infty,\infty]$ to $[0,1]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that works, and is a standard way of getting a metric on some space. We have

**Lemma:** Let $(X,\,d)$ a metric space, and $\varphi \colon Y \to X$ a bijection. Then $\delta \colon Y \times Y \to \mathbb{R};\; \delta(y,\,z) = d(\varphi(y),\,\varphi(z))$ is a metric on $Y$, and $\varphi$ is an isometry (in particular a homeomorphism) between $(Y,\,\delta)$ and $(X,\,d)$.

**Proof:** We have $\delta(y,\,z) \geqslant 0$, since $d$ takes only non-negative values, and

$$\delta(y,\,z) = 0 \iff d(\varphi(y),\,\varphi(z)) = 0 \iff \varphi(y) = \varphi(z) \iff y = z.$$

We have $\delta(y,\,z) = d(\varphi(y),\,\varphi(z)) = d(\varphi(z),\,\varphi(y)) = \delta(z,\,y)$, so $\delta$ is symmetric.

We have $\delta(x,\,z) = d(\varphi(x),\,\varphi(z)) \leqslant d(\varphi(x),\,\varphi(y)) + d(\varphi(y),\,\varphi(z)) = \delta(x,\,y) + \delta(y,\,z)$ for all $x,\,y,\,z \in Y$, hence $\delta$ satisfies the triangle inequality, hence is a metric.

By the very definition of $\delta$, $\varphi$ is an isometry $Y \to X$, hence also a homeomorphism for the topologies induced by $d$ resp. $\delta$.

Furthermore, we also have the

**Lemma:** Let $(Y,\tau)$ a topological space, and $(X,\,d)$ a metric space, and $\varphi \colon Y \to X$ a homeomorphism. Then the metric $\delta$ on $Y$ constructed as above induces the topology $\tau$ on $Y$.

**Proof:** Let $y \in Y$ and $V$ a $\tau$-neighbourhood of $y$. Since $\varphi$ is open (because it's a homeomorphism), $\varphi(V)$ is a neighbourhood of $\varphi(y)$, hence there is an $\varepsilon > 0$ with $d(x,\,\varphi(y)) < \varepsilon \Rightarrow x \in \varphi(V)$. But that means that $B^\delta_\varepsilon(y) = \{ z \in Y : \delta(z,\,y) < \varepsilon\} \subset V$, i.e. the topology induced by $\delta$ is finer than $\tau$.

Conversely, let $y \in Y$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then $\varphi(B^\delta_\varepsilon(y)) = B^d_\varepsilon(\varphi(y))$ is a neighbourhood of $\varphi(y)$, and by continuity of $\varphi$, there is a $\tau$-neighbourhood $V$ of $y$ with $\varphi(V) \subset B^d_\varepsilon(\varphi(y)) \iff V \subset B^\delta_\varepsilon(y)$, which means that $\tau$ is finer than the topology induced by $\delta$.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your detailed answer!
I'm studying stochastics mostly and I'm pretty disappointed that we never had topology, since we use basic results quite often. This explains my next probably easy question:
If I use $f$ to map open sets from $[0,1]$ (topology induced by $d$), are those the open sets in the topology of $\overline{d}$ (the transported metric)?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is a homeomorphism, so the open (closed) sets in $[-\infty,\, +\infty]$ are precisely the images of open (closed) sets in $[0,\,1]$ under $f$.

Comment: Got it, huge thank you again!